# What URL to use for InviteRedirectUrl when using New-AzureADMSInvitation for guest users?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I would like to set the URL to whatever value it uses when I invite a user from the interface, however, the parameter `InviteRedirectUrl` does not provide a default value and it is required.

I've tried testing it by sending myself an invite and it looks as though I'm redirected to 
https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/...

Is this to be expected?  Is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**InviteRedirectUrl** is the URL to which the invited user is forwarded after accepting the invitation. You can use your webapp website, such as `https://myapps.azure.com/`.

If you invite the guest user from Azure portal, it will be redirected to `https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/` by default.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion stemmed from the fact that I'm adding users to share Power BI reports and those reports haven't been created yet. Also, I don't have a webapp website.  With the number of invitations my preference would be to use PowerShell. Seemed odd to use the default of `https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/`

Answer (score 0):

I would add that you can use this to point users to other services, for example, when bulk adding B2B users (from other tenants) so they have access to an application I publish in AAD, I use the SAML login URL.

In that way, when the user accepts the invitation, they are redirected to the application, and since they are already members, they are automatically logged in.
In your specific case, you could use a placeholder for the reports (e.g. a page in SharePoint with PowerBI tiles), or they "home" in PowerBI, which you should set as https://app.powerbi.com/home?noSignUpCheck=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following url of microsoft http://myapps.microsoft.com
This works good for me.

Comment: How does this work? Is microsoft used as an alias for Azure?